# Is Selecting Multiple Items with a Two-Finger Pan Gesture only possible with UITableViewController?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer, pan

I tried implementing the selecting multiple items with a two-finger pan gesture. However, the checkmarks didn't always appear and disappear when tapping edit to start the process, or tapping done when finished.

I later discovered that it works fine when using a UITableViewController after choosing the different controller from cocoa touch menu, instead of the UIViewController and UITableView I was using before.

So my question is: is it correct for me to now assume that these gestures when used in a table are really meant for a dedicated table view controller (with all the extra functionality you only get from it)?

Answer (score -1):

Without any example code, I can't really see what might be going wrong. Have a look at the documentation to see if you are implementing it correctly.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/selecting_multiple_items_with_a_two-finger_pan_gesture